# Flutter Web Sitemap Generation

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, multilingual, sitemap

I am creating a website using flutter web, and need to create a Sitemap to post it to Google for site indexing. The Website is running in multiple languages and I need to create a Sitemap XML file per language.
Is there an easy way to create a sitemap automatically in Flutter Web? Any suggestion or insight is welcome

Comment: Facing the same issue. I created a sitemap.xml online for my website and added it inside the build/web folder. However search console still says Couldn't Fetch. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way yet. but as per the news flutter team is going to introduce a plugin for this.

Answer (score -1):

- create sitemap of your flutter website at "https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/"
- add your links manually in your sitemap.xml file (copy generated file/url and do it for each page of your fl web app)
- in ur terminal -> flutter pub add xml | or do it manually & insert xml: ^6.1.0 in ur pubspec.yaml
- create dart file, name it sitemap.dart or whatever
- add <- import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml; -> to this dart file
  => create stless Widget,
  add static const String route = 'sitemap.xml' add it to your main.dart file, where u're generated your routes like this:
  --> MaterialApp(title: 'MyApp', initialRoute: '/', routes:{SiteMap.route : (context) => SiteMap()}); ..
  add static const **sitemapxml** = '''
  <--- add here the input of your generated & manually changed sitemap.xml file --->
  '''
  => create final **document** = xml.XmlDocument.parse(**sitemapxml**);
  => add doc into TextWidget like this:

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Text(
**document.text**,
),
),
);
}

-> build web -- host your website -- index ur page again with your GoogleSearchConsole Account --> you'll see add new Sitemaps -- add it likes this. https://www.myhomepage.com/sitemap.xml
-- Index your website again, it will take to 24 hours to update it

-- now you're done.

Comment: This is bad advice. You should generate a sitemap from your database or code base, NOT with a crawler.   See [Google Says Don't Crawl Your Site To Build A Sitemap File](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-dont-crawl-your-site-sitemap-file-28453.html)